# Добавление имени элемента выпадающего списка в адресную строку

Tags: javascript, html

Есть выпадающий список, например:

```
<select id="select-city">
  <option value="">Select Your City...</option>
  <option data-slug="attard" value="1"> Attard </option>
  <option data-slug="bahar-ic-caghaq" value="2"> Bahar ic-Cagh</option>
</select>
```

И есть страница: eat/pages/sel_restaurans.html

Подскажите как сделать чтобы при выборе элемента списка происходил переход на эту страницу, а в адресную строку вместо pages/sel_restaurans.html добавлялось имя этого элемента
Например: eat/Attard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы реагировать на выбор элемента, можно использовать следующее:

```
$('select option:selected').click(function(){
  var value = $(this).val() || $(this).text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

Пример ссылки

```
pages/sel_restaurans.html?timetoeat/Attard
```

в Js вставь значение которое получил по клику в ссылку

Вот пример отлова выбора http://jsfiddle.net/Y5LsD/2/